# Confluence and synchrony can't start up

Tags: java, tomcat, confluence

### The problem

When I try to start the Confluence I always get this exception:

```
30-Aug-2017 08:44:03.053 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8091]:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

Here are the log and the server.xml:

- [catalina.log](https://gist.github.com/belovai/34bba5ae827002fba5b3a68e8d1f332b)
- [server.xml](https://gist.github.com/belovai/44371b6d84ce6239feea206998ebed2f)

My confluence version: confluence-6.3.1

### What have I noticed so far

When I start the confluence it spawns a process (at 08:41 AM)

```
conflue+  5430  264 19.6 4935920 1606444 pts/0 Sl   08:41   7:24 /opt/atlassian/confluence/jre//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dconfluence.context.path= -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options= -Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=32768 -Dsynchrony.enable.xhr.fallback=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseG1GC -Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300 -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/gc-2017-08-30_08-41-24.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:-PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/atlassian/confluence/endorsed -classpath /opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/confluence -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/confluence -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/confluence/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Which uses the 8090 port

```
netstat -nap |grep :::80
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      5430/java
```

Then it spawns another process (at 08:43 AM)

```
conflue+  5430  264 19.6 4935920 1606444 pts/0 Sl   08:41   7:24 /opt/atlassian/confluence/jre//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dconfluence.context.path= -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options= -Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=32768 -Dsynchrony.enable.xhr.fallback=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseG1GC -Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300 -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/gc-2017-08-30_08-41-24.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M -XX:-PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-PrintTenuringDistribution -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/atlassian/confluence/endorsed -classpath /opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/confluence -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/confluence -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/confluence/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
conflue+  5756 82.4  8.0 4665924 658816 pts/0  Sl   08:43   0:40 /opt/atlassian/confluence/jre/bin/java -classpath /opt/atlassian/confluence/temp/1.0.0-release-confluence_6.1-a1ab321e.jar:/opt/atlassian/confluence/confluence/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-42.1.1.jar -Xss2048k -Xmx1g synchrony.core sql
```

Which uses the 8091 port

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      5430/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      5756/java
```

And a few moments later it fails to start. If I kill the synchrony process (the second one) the confluence starts up correctly but I can't edit the documents because I'get `502` error on the `synchrony-proxy/heartbeat` url.

So what should I do? Can I put the synchrony to another port? Or the synchrony should start faster and free up the port? What is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchrony port can be changed with setting system property:

> Synchrony runs on port 8091 by default. If this port is already in use
>   by another application on your server you can use the the
>   **synchrony.port** system property to change it to an available port.

Additionally:

> Multiple Synchrony processes If you see an error immediatley in the
>   editor, but Confluence reports that Synchrony is running, check to
>   make sure that you only have one Synchrony process running.  If you do
>   have multiple Synchrony processes running, stop Confluence, kill the
>   additional Synchrony processes and then restart Confluence. You can
>   avoid this problem by always using stop-confluence.sh /
>   stop-confluence.bat to stop Confluence, rather than simply closing the
>   Tomcat window.

As described in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/troubleshooting-collaborative-editing-858772087.html)

Comment: Thank you. Well I've changed it but started on the same port so I've changed port in the server.xml. It starts up now correctly but now I get `401` error for the synchrony-proxy while editing a document...